# Responsive Web Wont work

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone I am trying to get my Navigation to be centered when it is on a screen size of 320 or less.  Really I want the logo centered at top then the navigation centered below followed by everything else.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <title>Jake Jones New Media Design</title>

      <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo"/></a></div>

<ul id="Menu">  
    <li>
    <a href="index.html">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html#web">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#campaign">Campaign</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#print">Print</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#motion">Motion</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#photography">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#vector">Vector</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
    <div class="text">

        <div class="imgContainer">
        <img src="img/me.jpg" style="width: 100%"/>
    </div>

        <p>
Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend        tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,  </p>

<div class="pdf">
<a href="resume.pdf">Resume</a>   |   
<a href="portfolio.pdf">Portfolio PDF</a> 
</div>

<div class="contact">
(330)285-3158 <br/>
<a href="mailto:thejonescreative@gmail.com">thejonescreative@gmail.com</a>
</div> 

    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
font-family: helvetica; 
font-size:12px; 
}

.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 980px;
width: auto;        
}

#logo {
float: left;
}

#Menu,
#Menu ul {
list-style: none;
}

#Menu {
float: right;
margin-top: 85px;
}

#Menu > li {
float: left;
}
#Menu li a {
display: block;
height: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
padding: 0 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
}

#Menu ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
}

#Menu ul li a {
width: 50px;
}

#Menu li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#Menu {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
background: #ffffff;
}

#Menu > li > a {
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
}

#Menu > li:hover > a {
background: #ffffff;
color: #7a0808;
}

/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#Menu ul {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
width: 100px;
}

#Menu ul li a {
color: #000000;
font-size: 13px;
```

}

```
#Menu ul li:hover a {
color: #7a0808;
}

/* Content
------------------------------------------*/
.text {
clear: both;
```

}

```
p {
padding-top: 70px;
padding-left: 40px;
width: 275px;
}


.imgContainer {
margin-top: 70px;
float:right;
clear: both;
padding-right: 15px;
}

.pdf {
padding-left: 40px;
}

.pdf a:link {
color: black;
```

}

```
.pdf a:hover {
color: #7a0808;
}

.pdf a:visited {
color: #838383;
}

.contact {
line-height: 17px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 40px;
}

.contact a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

img {
    max-width:100%}

}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 300px){
#logo {
    width: 50%
    }

   #Menu a:link {
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your style img tag have two closing brackets remove the last one it should look like this

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

for responsive add following code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
#logo {
    text-align:center;
    float:none;
    }
#Menu{
    float:none;
}
#Menu > li {
margin-right: 15px;
}
   #Menu a:link {
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

Checkout on http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/vmcrtej3/

Answer (score -1):

I think you must write CSS for class wrapper and id logo in media screen 300 px also. try this you will be able to find it responsive.